# How to make cell save when slickgrid looses focus

Tags: slickgrid

I have a SlickGrid with some Editors on a form with some buttons above it. (Save and Cancel). When i edit a cell in the grid and click the buttons above the grid - the cell does not commit it's edit. I've debugged and it is not calling : commitCurrentEdit. I've also tested on clicking an empty area anywhere out of the grid area...

Has anyone noticed this scenario and have a solution to get the cell to commit when one clicks out of the grid. Due to the various positions the grid good be in it would be hard to do an overlay.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$("#buttonName").bind("click", function(){
  gridName.getEditController().commitCurrentEdit()
});
```